# Need help creating the following sequence:

Tags: r

In R, I need to create a vector `b = (1, 1+pi, 1+2pi, 1+3pi,...,1+19pi)`. I am unsure how to do this. I keep trying to use the `seq` command (i.e. `seq(1, 1+npi n = 1:19)` and that's totally wrong!), but don't know the proper syntax to make it work, thus it never does.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

R needs the multiplication operator.

```
b <- 1+ seq(0,19)*pi
```

Or slightly faster in situations where speed might matter:

```
 b <- 1+ seq.int(0,19)*pi
```

You could use the equivalent:

```
b <- 1+ 0:19*pi
```

Because the ":" operator has very high precedence ( see `?Syntax`), it's reasonable safe. Just be careful that you understand precedence when you use a minus or plus sign where it might be parse as a binary operator (remembering that spaces are ignored and that unary-minus has higher precedence than the single-colon, but binary minus or plus has a lower precedence :

```
> 1: 5+5
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use simply `0:19 * pi + 1`. Using `seq` is not so nice: `seq(1, 1 + 19 * pi, by = pi)` or `seq(1, 1 + 19 * pi, length = 20)`.

Comment: I think 0:19 * pi + 1 for the requested sequence starting with 1, and if you started with 1+pi, then the `by` increment should be 1, not pi

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. It's good to finally get over that obstacle!